# About the ehcache generating the disk file name

Tags: ehcache

I added three types cache in ehcache as show below:

```
<cache name="oneDayCache" ...
<cache name="threeHourCache"  ...
<cache name="oneHourCache"  ...
<cache name="fifteenMinsCache"  ...
```

but when I checked the file generated by ehcache in the disk, the file name is not pretty, charactors changed when meeting a capital.

```
one%0048our%0043ache.data
....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a feature, because Ehcache cannot be sure the underlying file system is case-sensitive while cache names are. If you really must have clean file names, do not camel case your cache names but instead use a separator such as `_` or `-`.

More details can be found in `net.sf.ehcache.DiskStorePathManager#safeName`